# Completion square method quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, quadratic-forms, completing-the-square

$-6xy-6xz+3y^2+6yz-2z^2$

I've already tried to factor out some variables, but I am always left with 3 variables again after my transformation. I've tried $(a+b)^2$ and $(a+b+c)^2$, I guess I need some methodology, I really rely on you, guys >.<

Comment: i only found this here $$-2\, \left( z-3/2\,y+3/2\,x \right) ^{2}+3\, \left( y-x \right) ^{2}-3
\,{x}^{2}+1/8\, \left( 6\,y-6\,x \right) ^{2}
$$

Comment: $$3(x-y)^2+3(x-z)^2+3(y+z)^2-6x^2-3y^2-8z^2$$ Is this the expression you want ?

Comment: Or with only $3$ squares ; $$3(y+z-x)^2-3x^2-5z^2$$

Comment: @Alice do you want to solve an equation or to simplify this expression ?

Comment: @Peter this is probably indefinite quadratic form, I presume?

Comment: @Peter but I really can't understand how are you people are managed to get to this elegant solution 

Comment: Alice, read algorithm at  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr  and some of the links i put there.  The matrix is the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives of the form. In your case, you can take half the Hessian matrix and still have all integer entries.

Answer (score 0):

Complete the square to deal with all the $z$'s
\begin{eqnarray*}
-2(z-\frac{3}{2}y +\frac{3}{2}x)^2 + ...
\end{eqnarray*}
Now complete the square for the $x$'s
\begin{eqnarray*}
-2(z-\frac{3}{2}y +\frac{3}{2}x)^2 + \frac{1}{2} (3 x -5y)^2 -5y^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you, but how did you "saw" what variable we should handle first?  I'm really interested in the algorithm of solution, I'd be glad to get a piece of advice, if u have time 

Comment: The order is up to handle the variables is up to you ... indeed Peter's solution shows that there is a better/easier way than the one that I give.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a purely algorithmic approach is $Q^T D Q = H,$ where half the Hessian of your quadratic form is $H,$ then $D$ is diagonal, and $Q$ has determinant $\pm 1.$  I show the matrices first. The method, an algorithm,  is discussed in detail at my http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

===============================================================

```
? qt
%17 = 
[-3/2 3/5 -1]

[3/2 -1 0]

[-1 0 0]

? d
%18 = 
[-2 0 0]

[0 15/2 0]

[0 0 9/5]

? q
%19 = 
[-3/2 3/2 -1]

[3/5 -1 0]

[-1 0 0]

? qt * d * q
%20 = 
[0 0 -3]

[0 3 3]

[-3 3 -2]

?
```

===============================================================

The whole thing:

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500509
? h = [ 0,0,-3; 0,3,3; -3,3,-2]
%1 = 
[0 0 -3]

[0 3 3]

[-3 3 -2]

? ht = mattranspose(h)
%2 = 
[0 0 -3]

[0 3 3]

[-3 3 -2]

? h - ht
%3 = 
[0 0 0]

[0 0 0]

[0 0 0]

? p1 = [ 0,0,1; 0,1,0; 1,0,0]
%4 = 
[0 0 1]

[0 1 0]

[1 0 0]

? h1 = p1 * h * p1
%5 = 
[-2 3 -3]

[3 3 0]

[-3 0 0]

? p2 = [ 1, 3/2, -3/2; 0,1,0; 0,0,1]
%6 = 
[1 3/2 -3/2]

[0 1 0]

[0 0 1]

? p2t = mattranspose(p2)
%7 = 
[1 0 0]

[3/2 1 0]

[-3/2 0 1]

? h2 = p2t * h1 * p2
%8 = 
[-2 0 0]

[0 15/2 -9/2]

[0 -9/2 9/2]

? p3 = [ 1,0,0; 0,1, 9/15; 0,0,1]
%9 = 
[1 0 0]

[0 1 3/5]

[0 0 1]

? p3t = mattranspose(p3)
%10 = 
[1 0 0]

[0 1 0]

[0 3/5 1]

? h3 = p3t * h2 * p3
%11 = 
[-2 0 0]

[0 15/2 0]

[0 0 9/5]

? d = h3 
%12 = 
[-2 0 0]

[0 15/2 0]

[0 0 9/5]

? p = p1 * p2 * p3
%13 = 
[0 0 1]

[0 1 3/5]

[1 3/2 -3/5]

? matdet(p)
%14 = -1
? q = matadjoint(p)
%15 = 
[-3/2 3/2 -1]

[3/5 -1 0]

[-1 0 0]

? qt = mattranspose(q)
%16 = 
[-3/2 3/5 -1]

[3/2 -1 0]

[-1 0 0]

? qt
%17 = 
[-3/2 3/5 -1]

[3/2 -1 0]

[-1 0 0]

? d
%18 = 
[-2 0 0]

[0 15/2 0]

[0 0 9/5]

? q
%19 = 
[-3/2 3/2 -1]

[3/5 -1 0]

[-1 0 0]

? qt * d * q
%20 = 
[0 0 -3]

[0 3 3]

[-3 3 -2]

?
```

===============================================================